# Online JTAG / RGH Source Code Compile Time Errors

Tags: c++, xbox, jtag

I am trying to compile this source for the JTAG/RGH online server method. I got errors when trying to compile. Below is the output error log.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: client, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  CAssemblerDlg.cpp
1>e:\jtag\socket server\socket server\windows\cassemblerdlg.cpp(104): error C2065: 'm_hListControl' : undeclared identifier
1>e:\jtag\socket server\socket server\windows\cassemblerdlg.cpp(107): error C2065: 'm_hListControl' : undeclared identifier
1>e:\jtag\socket server\socket server\windows\cassemblerdlg.cpp(110): error C2065: 'm_hListControl' : undeclared identifier
1>e:\jtag\socket server\socket server\windows\cassemblerdlg.cpp(113): error C2065: 'm_hListControl' : undeclared identifier
1>e:\jtag\socket server\socket server\windows\cassemblerdlg.cpp(114): error C2065: 'm_hListControl' : undeclared identifier
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

If anyone can help me it would be great.

Comment: Can you share link to your source code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forgot to include some headers where `m_hListControl` were declared.

I'm saying so, because `m_*` prefix often used for class private members.

Here is extract from MSDN:

#### [Compiler Error C2065](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewcf0002.aspx)

A variable's type must be **specified** in a declaration **before** it can be used. The parameters that a function uses must be specified in a declaration, or prototype, before the function can be used.

Possible causes:

1. Omitting necessary include files.
2. Identifier name is misspelled.
3. Identifier uses the wrong uppercase and lowercase letters.
4. Missing closing quote after a string constant.
5. Improper namespace scope.